# Using Excel to return a yes/no response from a data table, using multiple conditions in separate columns

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I'm trying to refine a report dashboard utilized at my workplace. The process that I'm trying to automate is;

- Data is generated into a worksheet via a query table (Worksheet called Imported Data)
- From that table, i'm wanting to look at 3 separate columns for 3 conditions
- Those conditions are a) Team, B) Frequency, C) Month and D) Yes (from a ye/no option)

Providing all those conditions are met Eg, Team A, Monthly, February, Yes, I want Excel to produce a response of Compliant, otherwise say Non-compliant, onto another worksheet called Governance Complaince

The response for this is on a separate work sheet.

The main query table that is generated has around 8 Team choices, 6 Frequency options, with 12 month and then the 2 (obviously) yes/no options.

I've tried a few different formulas to get this to work, but I only ever get the True value from the formula.

I Feel that maybe the formula is stopping once it sees the first Team A selection (Which by nature of how the query table is generated, is the first result in the Team column) and then ignoring the remainder of the formula, despite my best attempts.

The current formula I'm using is

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!A:A,"Team A")+COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!C:C,"Monthly")+COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!F:F,"February")+COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!I:I,"Yes")>1,"Compliant","Non-compliant")
```

I've tried

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!A:A,"Team A")+COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!C:C,"Monthly")+COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!F:F,"February")+COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!I:I,"Yes")=ROWS('Imported Data'!A1:Z500),"Compliant","Non-compliant")
```

```
=IF(AND('Imported Data'!A:A,"Team A")+AND('Imported Data'!C:C,"Monthly")+AND('Imported Data'!F:F,"February")+AND('Imported Data'!I:I,"Yes"),"Compliant","Non-compliant")
```

```
=IF(AND('Imported Data'!A:A,"Team A")+AND('Imported Data'!C:C,"Monthly")+AND('Imported Data'!F:F,"February")+AND('Imported Data'!I:I,"Yes")=ROWS('Imported Data'!A1:Z500),"Compliant","Non-compliant")
```

All I get is a #Value error, or only the Compliant value, despite any changes made to the data the formula references.

All the cells are text, there is no numerical data in the tables. The formula is placed into a cell in another worksheet called Governance Compliance

Essentially I want the formula to be able to look at the query table data, output the Ture/False value into a monthly tracker (This formula will be replicated over about 26 different audits for 8 teams) automatically, cutting down on manual processing. I've been able to get the date to then look at a quarterly array of teams and return a complaint/non-complaint result into another worksheet fine using

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Governance Compliance'!E11:G19,"Compliant")=ROWS('Governance Compliance'!E11:G19),"Yes","No")
```

And I thought that my 3 condition if statement to get the compliant result into the Governance Compliance worksheet would just be an expansion of conditions on this formula, but I am clearly wrong.

The query table is sorted alphabetically by Team if that makes a difference.

Comment: Change the `+` to `*` .  `+` means `Or` and `*` means `And`

Comment: Thanks Scott, tried that and it still only returns the True value.

I change the + to a * and tried both of these

=IF(COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!A:A,"Team A")*COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!C:C,"Monthly")*COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!F:F,"February")*COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!I:I,"Yes"),"Compliant","Non-compliant")

And 

=IF(COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!A:A,"Team A")*COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!C:C,"Monthly")*COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!F:F,"February")*COUNTIFS('Imported Data'!I:I,"Yes")=ROWS('Imported Data'!A1:Z500),"Compliant","Non-compliant")

But no joy

Comment: I think you need to use SUMPRODUCT instead of COUNTIFS. Using virtual matrix you obtain your goal, is valid @ScottCraner tip for using `+` and `*` as boolean operators